# How does iodic(VII) acid oxidise amines?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, organic-oxidation

What happens when 3‐aminobutan‐2‐one undergoes oxidative cleavage with $\ce{HIO4}?$

[image: 3‐aminobutan‐2‐one]

I'm particularly interested in the amine part. Would the hydroxy and amino groups on the same carbon be stable? Or would it undergo some sort of rearrangement?

Comment: The primary amine will get oxidised to the hydroxylamine which will readily hydrolyse to the ketone giving the 2,3-diketone, see https://www.thermofisher.com/uk/en/home/references/molecular-probes-the-handbook/reagents-for-modifying-groups-other-than-thiols-or-amines/hydrazines-hydroxylamines-and-aromatic-amines-for-modifying-aldehydes-and-ketones.html

Comment: So does that mean there's no oxidative cleavage?

Comment: Correct - no oxidative cleavage